# Laravel Assets Folder Not accesible

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I cant access my public folder by Laravel default functions:

My css is inside
Public->css->app.css

When I write the code

```
{{asset('css/app.css')}}
```

Which means `view-source:http://localhost:8000/css/app.css`

It says not found I try it with `URL` function as well, it still seems not possible.

I also tried accessing this

```
{{ \Storage::url(config('settings.app.logo')) . getPictureVersion() }}
```

But still couldnt understand what it says?

Anything missing I am? Well I am new to laravel

Comment: where is your index.php file? is it in public folder or in main directory?

Comment: In your .env file set the `APP_URL` to whatever you have as base url of your site.

Comment: @dparoli, I have localhost:8000 as my APP_URL do i need to make change?

Comment: That depends on your base url, I don't know what it is, you never said if that is your real base url or not.

Comment: does your server have read access to the file?

Comment: Are you using `php artisan serve` to serve your app or do you have a webserver set up? Is `localhost:8000` the actual URL of your app? Are you using Webpack/Mix to compile your assets? Try `{{mix('css/app.css')}}`

Comment: @kerbholz, Understood your point perfectly, but what is then {{ \Storage::url(config('settings.app.logo')) . getPictureVersion() }} here? Storage URL?

Comment: You can read more about Laravel's filesystem [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem).